# ListView - CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL - Random items are being selected

Tags: java, android, android-listview

Basically, I have a bug where some of my list view's children will appear selected, when in fact they are not. For example, If I enter `ActionMode` and select the first child only, several other children will appear as though I've selected them, but aren't actually selected. Why is this happening?

```
public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
            long id, boolean checked) {
        final int checkedCount = lv.getCheckedItemCount();
        mSelectedConvCount.setText(Integer.toString(checkedCount));
        if (checked) {
            lv.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.BLUE);
        } else {
            lv.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
                    Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you can't just use getChildAt method with position as parameter to get the child view. The the postition of child is different.

Comment: @user674199 Looks to me like I'm already doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: In a `ListView`, anything you set or change in any child views must be set every time they are displayed; all you are doing in the code provided is setting it initially. This means your adapter must also `setBackgroundColor` as appropriate, e.g. in `bindView()`. Otherwise, when the view is recycled it will retain the previous background color and appear selected when it is not.